# Page reload on submit in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function HeroSection() {
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior
console.log(email); // Log the email or perform other actions like sending to an API
};

return (
<main className="flex justify-center flex-col items-center">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<input
type="text"
placeholder="Enter your email"
value={email}
onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
/>
<button type="submit">Get Started</button>
</form>
<h1>{email}</h1>
</main>
);
}
```

```
import HeroSection from './HeroSection'export 
default function Home() 
{return 
(
<main className="flex h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
<HeroSection/>
</main>
)}
```

i am new to next, but got stuck on this basic thing, why does my page refresh on clicking "Get started" button?

I am just trying to play with nextjs but got on this basic stuff!